# PHP Code to stop a script to run from browser

Tags: php, browser, cron

Envoirnment : Linux, PHP

Scenario : I have written a script which will be set as a cron. Now the case is that I want  the script to run only through cron and not through any browser (any web browser including mobile browsers). So I am looking for a function something like browserValidate.

The script is written in MVC framework and will be run as

```
/usr/bin/GET http://xyz.com/abc/pqr
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a web based MVC framework to write a script that you want to trigger from cron? Just access your model library from a command line script.

Comment: there are lots of functions which are used in the script which are defined in the framework. Hence I am using MVC

Comment: The question is why you have given web access to the script in the first place if you don't wish it to be run from the browser?

Comment: @AbhishekSanghvi — Sounds like those functions should be moved to a shared library.

Answer (score 9):

As @Mob said, the sure fire way to achieve this is to put the script in a place where it cannot be accessed through the web server. If this is not possible or you don't want to do it for some reason, you need to detect whether the script was called via a web server or through the command line.

My favourite approach for this (there are many) is:

```
$isRunningFromBrowser = !isset($GLOBALS['argv']);
```

This means that if `$isRunningFromBrowser` is true, you just exit/return an error message/whatever.

Comment: The OP edited the question. The script is executed with a `wget`-like binary. So no `argv`. Also, PHP running as FastCGI will contain `argv` in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: @LinusKleen I have never had an FCGI environment and the does potentially throw a spanner in the works - does it still define `$argv` in the global scope as well, or just an entry in `$_SERVER`?

Comment: My bad, @Dave. `$_SERVER` *only*. No globals to see.

Comment: No worries, your answer is still the more relevant solution because of the edit which means that cron is still making an HTTP request. Although the OPs approach is all wrong using cron/wget is vastly inferior to just writing a command line script, so I will leave this answer here in the hope that someone persuades him to do this. You have a +1 from me though because your solution fits his current approach.

Answer (score 8):

When executing the script from within crontab, you could use the `$_SERVER` superglobal to either check for Apache generated entries (`HTTP_*`) or - since `$_SERVER` reflects the executing binary's environment - define a certain environment variable prior to execution:

```
# in the crontab
FOOVAR=1 /usr/bin/php5 script.php
```

Then, in script.php, check for `FOOVAR` existence:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['FOOVAR']))
   die('No browser access.');
```

---

If your cronjob is being executed with `wget` and the client IP is the server's, you could add this to an `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "192.168.0.1" FOOVAR=1
```

This will set `FOOVAR` only if the client's IP address is "192.168.0.1".

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how environment variables are set for the HTTP request the OP does in question ^^

Answer (score 1):

I've edited this to explain better:

Since you're using /usr/bin/GET to fetch a page via HTTP I'm assuming that you have two separate servers:
First, one that PHP script is on and where you can't run cron scripts.
Second, one where you are running the /usr/bin/GET fetch in cron as a workaround for that.

A simple way might be to simply post a unique identifier in the url and check in the script 
like:

```
/usr/bin/GET http://xyz.com/abc/pqr/SomeUniqueIdentifier
```

Another way could be to use the -H option with /usr/bin/GET to set the User-Agent header to something unique like:

/usr/bin/GET -H "User-Agent: SomeUniqueIdentifier" http://xyz.com/abc/pqr

The PHP script would then check the user agent string for this unique identifier like:

```
if (strcmp($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "SomeUniqueIdentifier") == 0)
{
   // do whatever
}
else
{
   // do nothing
   exit();
}
```

Neither way is 100% secure but can help out.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way is to check the request ip address and only run if it is the local host ip.

Of course, you need to add some more code later (check user agent, referer etc..) to make sure that even a browser locally does not trigger the script.

Answer (score 0):

Move the script outside of the web directory and execute it on the command line. Parse the arguments to the script for the appropriate GET and POST variable population.

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#94912